# CSS on Android app Phonegap not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

So today I tried building up an Android app using this tutorial: http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/phonegapcordova-android-app-in-mountain-lion-with-eclipse-from-install-to-google-play/

All worked fine, but when I emulate the app, some elements of the css dont work.
The java script works and the html too. But for example word colors and sizes, gradients and much more simply doesnt work.

The only css that did work was the background color that was blue. I dunno if that helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/wsxWZ/

and the css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CallunaSansRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/calluna-sans/CallunaSansRegular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/calluna-sans/CallunaSansRegular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/calluna-sans/CallunaSansRegular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/calluna-sans/CallunaSansRegular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/calluna-sans/CallunaSansRegular-webfont.svg#CallunaSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: franchise-bold;
    src: url('../fonts/Franchise-Bold.ttf');
    font-weight:normal;
}






body {
    font: 15px CallunaSansRegular;
    width: 980px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: black;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav>a{
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 1%;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    height: 20px;


    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#friends{

background: #c5deea; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%, #8abbd7 31%, #066dab 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c5deea), color-stop(31%,#8abbd7), color-stop(100%,#066dab)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c5deea', endColorstr='#066dab',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */



/*     background-color: blue; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    padding-top: 2%;
}

article{
    position: relative;
/*     background-color: gray;     */
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 3.5%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 3.5%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;


/*     box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #000000; */


background: #aebcbf; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%, #6e7774 50%, #0a0e0a 51%, #0a0809 100%, #0a0809 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#aebcbf), color-stop(50%,#6e7774), color-stop(51%,#0a0e0a), color-stop(100%,#0a0809), color-stop(100%,#0a0809)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aebcbf', endColorstr='#0a0809',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}


.online{
    background: #9dd53a; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9dd53a 0%, #a1d54f 50%, #80c217 51%, #7cbc0a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#9dd53a), color-stop(50%,#a1d54f), color-stop(51%,#80c217), color-stop(100%,#7cbc0a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9dd53a 0%,#a1d54f 50%,#80c217 51%,#7cbc0a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #9dd53a 0%,#a1d54f 50%,#80c217 51%,#7cbc0a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #9dd53a 0%,#a1d54f 50%,#80c217 51%,#7cbc0a 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9dd53a 0%,#a1d54f 50%,#80c217 51%,#7cbc0a 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9dd53a', endColorstr='#7cbc0a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}





h1{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 4px;
      left: 43%;
      color: white;
}

.coisos{

    padding: 5%;    
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;


}

.coisos>a{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;

    font-size: large;
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;

/*     box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #000000; */



background: #aebcbf; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%, #6e7774 50%, #0a0e0a 51%, #0a0809 100%, #0a0809 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#aebcbf), color-stop(50%,#6e7774), color-stop(51%,#0a0e0a), color-stop(100%,#0a0809), color-stop(100%,#0a0809)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aebcbf', endColorstr='#0a0809',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}


.coisos>a:hover{
    background: #3b679e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%, #2b88d9 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3b679e), color-stop(50%,#2b88d9), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3b679e', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}



article:hover{
    background: #3b679e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%, #2b88d9 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3b679e), color-stop(50%,#2b88d9), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3b679e', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}









#search{
    background: #c5deea; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%, #8abbd7 31%, #066dab 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c5deea), color-stop(31%,#8abbd7), color-stop(100%,#066dab)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c5deea', endColorstr='#066dab',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */




    /* background-color: blue; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    padding-top: 2%;
}


.search{
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    float: left;
    width: 93%;
    height: 90px;
/*     background-color: red; */


background: #55aa9e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%, #b6eace 50%, #0a302d 51%, #285760 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#55aa9e), color-stop(50%,#b6eace), color-stop(51%,#0a302d), color-stop(100%,#285760)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#55aa9e', endColorstr='#285760',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}

.sear{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

input{
    height: 60px;
}

.seartex{
    width: 80%;
}

.butsear{
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.log{
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    float: left;
    width: 93%;
    height: 200px;
/*     background-color: red; */


background: #55aa9e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%, #b6eace 50%, #0a302d 51%, #285760 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#55aa9e), color-stop(50%,#b6eace), color-stop(51%,#0a302d), color-stop(100%,#285760)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#55aa9e', endColorstr='#285760',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}



form{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder
}

.un{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 700px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.un>input{
    width: 60%;

}

.pwd{
    float: right;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
}

.pwd>input{
    width: 60%;
}

#login{
    background: #c5deea; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%, #8abbd7 31%, #066dab 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c5deea), color-stop(31%,#8abbd7), color-stop(100%,#066dab)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c5deea', endColorstr='#066dab',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */




    /* background-color: blue; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    padding-top: 2%;
}



.navlog{
    background-color: #c5deea;
}

.navfrien{
    background-color: #c5deea;
}

.navsear{
    background-color: #c5deea;
}

.navperfil{
    background-color: #c5deea;
}



.navlog:hover{
    background-color: gray;
}

.navfrien:hover{
    background-color: gray;
}

.navsear:hover{
    background-color: gray;
}

.navperfil:hover{
    background-color: gray;
}

.offline{
    background: #f85032; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f85032 0%, #f16f5c 50%, #f6290c 51%, #f02f17 71%, #e73827 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f85032), color-stop(50%,#f16f5c), color-stop(51%,#f6290c), color-stop(71%,#f02f17), color-stop(100%,#e73827)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f85032 0%,#f16f5c 50%,#f6290c 51%,#f02f17 71%,#e73827 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f85032 0%,#f16f5c 50%,#f6290c 51%,#f02f17 71%,#e73827 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f85032 0%,#f16f5c 50%,#f6290c 51%,#f02f17 71%,#e73827 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f85032 0%,#f16f5c 50%,#f6290c 51%,#f02f17 71%,#e73827 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f85032', endColorstr='#e73827',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}





.coisos1{
    margin-top: 500px;
    padding: 5%;    
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;


}

.coisos1>a{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;

    font-size: large;
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;

/*     box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #000000; */



background: #aebcbf; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%, #6e7774 50%, #0a0e0a 51%, #0a0809 100%, #0a0809 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#aebcbf), color-stop(50%,#6e7774), color-stop(51%,#0a0e0a), color-stop(100%,#0a0809), color-stop(100%,#0a0809)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%,#0a0809 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aebcbf', endColorstr='#0a0809',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}


.coisos1>a:hover{
    background: #3b679e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%, #2b88d9 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3b679e), color-stop(50%,#2b88d9), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3b679e 0%,#2b88d9 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3b679e', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}




.log1{
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    float: left;
    width: 93%;
    height: 200px;
/*     background-color: red; */


background: #55aa9e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%, #b6eace 50%, #0a302d 51%, #285760 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#55aa9e), color-stop(50%,#b6eace), color-stop(51%,#0a302d), color-stop(100%,#285760)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#55aa9e', endColorstr='#285760',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}

.log2{
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    float: left;
    width: 93%;
    height: 500px;
/*     background-color: red; */


background: #55aa9e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%, #b6eace 50%, #0a302d 51%, #285760 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#55aa9e), color-stop(50%,#b6eace), color-stop(51%,#0a302d), color-stop(100%,#285760)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#55aa9e', endColorstr='#285760',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}

.log3{
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    float: left;
    width: 93%;
    height: 120px;
/*     background-color: red; */


background: #55aa9e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%, #b6eace 50%, #0a302d 51%, #285760 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#55aa9e), color-stop(50%,#b6eace), color-stop(51%,#0a302d), color-stop(100%,#285760)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #55aa9e 0%,#b6eace 50%,#0a302d 51%,#285760 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#55aa9e', endColorstr='#285760',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}

.titulo{
    float: left;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.foto{
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: right;
    height:90%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: gray;
}


.contain{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    height:40%;
    width: 20%;

}

.contain>p{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contain1{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    height:40%;
    width: 70%;
}

.contain1>p{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 35px;
}


#perfil{

background: #c5deea; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%, #8abbd7 31%, #066dab 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c5deea), color-stop(31%,#8abbd7), color-stop(100%,#066dab)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c5deea 0%,#8abbd7 31%,#066dab 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c5deea', endColorstr='#066dab',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */



/*     background-color: blue; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
```

Comment: Some code would really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment the way I fixed this was to use css within the html file.

ex:

```
<a style="color: red;"></a>
```

And everything works now (except the gradients and shadows, but that prolly has to do with the webkits I used).